# Refresh Data from Servlet on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I send continuously data per POST to my Servlet 'data.java'. I forward the data per Request Dispatcher to my JSP, where the data should be shown in real time (Change on every gotten POST in 'data.java').

Servlet 'data.java'

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("x")+" "+request.getParameter("y")+" "+request.getParameter("z"));

    String x = request.getParameter("x");
    String y = request.getParameter("y");
    String z = request.getParameter("z");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("xpos", x);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("ypos", y);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("zpos", z);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/folder/Page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

The console shows the exact data I sent to the Servlet. So the data should be received and put into the respective String Variables. But the JSP doesn't show the forwarded data at all. Like the String 'x' is empty. When I replace "x" to a local created counter. It shows the counter, when the page is refreshed.

JSP 'Page.jsp'

```
<p>X: <span id="xpos"> </span></p>
<p>X: <span id="xxx"> </span></p>
<p>Y: <span id="yyy"> </span></p>
<p>Z: <span id="zzz"> </span></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        xpos.innerHTML = <%=request.getAttribute("xpos")%>;

        xxx.innerHTML = '${xpos}';
        yyy.innerHTML = '${ypos}';
        zzz.innerHTML = '${zpos}';
    },20);
</script>
```

The "<%=request.getAttribute("xpos")%>" shows NULL and "'${xpos}'" is just empty. The data range is from -250 to 250.

Another problem is, that the data is only updated, when the JSP gets reloaded. Can you tell me how I show the data continuously?

Comment: You should read about the HTTP protocol. Your page does not get updated with real-time data without some work. Read about websockets and ajax polling.

Comment: [Asynchronous processing with Servlet 3.0](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html) and
[WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) will be helpful